# Sort listview by similarity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I have a task app.

Its table is being created by

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
                TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

My goal is to list those items in a listview using a listviewadapter such that similar `TASK_TITLE`s are grouped together.

Example listview

```
Go running 2 times
40 tomatoes
Go running 5 times
Go hunting
Buy two running shoes
tomatoes, 400g
```

should be

```
Go running 2 times
Go running 5 times
Buy two running shoes
40 tomatoes
tomatoes, 400g
Go hunting
```

as

```
Go running 2 times
Go running 5 times
Buy two running shoes
```

contains `running` and

```
40 tomatoes
tomatoes, 400g
```

contains `tomatoes`

Comment: You tried hard but your question is not clear enough right now . can you be more specific ? Maybe add few rows of data as well .

Comment: What if instead of `Buy two running shoes` the value is `Buy two running tomatoes`? Have you thought of all the possibilities?

Comment: @forpas Thanks for your hint. After you wrote it, I realized that this can be solved by nouns versus verbs. Verbs rank lower than nouns. Therefore, `Buy two running tomatoes` would go to `tomatoes`, not `running`.

Comment: Do you have some kind of a dictionary that can be stored in a SQLite database where words can be defined as nouns, verbs etc? Because as far as I know, at this level of programming apps for Android, there is no way to distinguish between these categories.

Comment: @ADM it is specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list (list2).

```
for(i=0;i<list1.size;i++){  
   if(list1[i].contains("running")), add to list2.  
   if(list1[i].contains("tomatoes")), add to list2.
}
```

adjust the conditions as i just hinted the flow. It Should resolve the problem.
assign the list2 to adapter.

Comment: Do you think this is funny?